# Is there a way to locate an element from the page source (not from the DOM)?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit4

I am using Selenium Webdriver,Junit and the Java language. I have to find an element from the source of the page.  driver.getPageSource() doesn't seem to return the desired value from the pagesource.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you are unable to use a lookup by ID, class, CSS selector or XPath?

Comment: what do you mean by "not from the DOM"?

Comment: I have to compare two values. Once is given on the  GUI(or in the DOM) and the other is accessed via pagesource. On the GUI (or DOM) I can locate the  element from ID,class,css selector etc but these commands do not work for the element present in source HTML (page source).

Comment: ...yes they do. That's what they're for; locating objects in HTML.

Comment: If you are having issues not being able to locate certain elements, install firebug and then the addon firepath to it.  Inspect whatever element you are looking for and ensure that it is not in a frame. Unless the item you are looking for is inside of Flash, you should be able to find it by the selectors mentioned above.

Comment: DOM/GUI/Page source are always in sync when it comes to display. Atleast major browsers made sure this works. If a page wants to display a value 10 in it's source..u see the same value in DOM & in UI too

Comment: Hi All, If you think I can locate the value from the pagesource, can you please let mme know  the code/coomand that I can use. As

Comment: Hi All, If you think I can locate the value from the pagesource, can you please let mme know  the code/coomand that I can use.  As driver.pagesource.* does not locate an element from the page source. As mentioned earlier the value is not present in the DOM.(There is no such command as driver.pagesource.findelement(By.*).

Answer (score 0):

On the page source you should use a Java xml parser.
See example here: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html